# Suppose that X is an exponential random variable... Chebychev's Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

Suppose that X is an exponential random variable with pdf $f(x)=e^{-x}$ for $0<x<\infty$ and 0 otherwise. Find the exact probability that X takes on a value more than two standard deviations away from its mean.

So here is what I did... I found the mean or $E(X)=1$ and the $Var(X)=1$ and the standard deviation to be 1. Now the probability I want to calculate is what I have no clue how to set up I thought I would want to calculate $P(X>2)$ but I do not think that is right?

The other question I don't know how to do is to use Chebychev's inequality to find a bound on this probability.

Can you please help with setting up the correct probability so I can go to Chebychev's inequality?

Comment: You don't need Chebychev's inequality. Since you know the distribution, you can compute the exact probability.

Comment: sorry, misread you post, you want to calculate $P(X> 1+2\sigma)=1-P(X\leq 1+2\sigma)$

Comment: so is that really $1-P(X\le 3)$?

Comment: yes...but just because X takes only non-negative values

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathrm E(X) = 1$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X)  =1$, the probability that $X$ takes on a value more than two standard deviations away from its mean is
$$
\mathrm P(|X-1| > 2) = \mathrm P(X < -1) +  \mathrm P(X > 3).
$$

Both of these terms are easy to compute for the exponential distribution.
You should find $e^{-3} \approx 0.05$

On the other hand, Chebyshev's inequality only yields the upper bound
$$
\mathrm P(|X-1| > 2) \leq \frac{1}{2^2}\mathrm{Var}(X) = 0.25
$$

Comment: okay I can compute that easily.  How do I use Cheychev's inequality to find a bound on this probability?

Comment: @AlyssaWallace: see my edit.

Comment: to calculate the first probability it would be 0 + F(3) where $F(X) = -e^{-x}$ so I am getting -0.049 which can't be right... where did I go wrong?

Comment: @AlyssaWallace : $P(X > t) = e^{-t}$ for $t > 0$.

Comment: Why? sorry just want to make sure I understand I did the integral of my pdf to get the cdf to evaluate to find the P(X>3)

Comment: Be more careful with the computation of the integral. $P(X > t) =  \int_t^\infty e^{-x}dx = e^{-t}$ and $P(X \leq t) = \int_0^t e^{-x}dx = 1 - e^{-t}$. Of course $e^{-t} + 1 - e^{-t} = 1$, which is not surprising.

Comment: So how would you do $P(X\lt5)$?

Comment: $P(X < 5) = P(X \leq 5) = 1 - e^{-5}$